# Manipulation of 'success' data breaks recursive ajax

Tags: ajax

I am writing an automatic script to do crawl jobs. I put the ajax function in a recursive function to automate the process. The whole thing works that the ajax function keeps fetching URLs from the list array. However, it stops working after I put this code: `$("#myframe").html(temp.body);`, where `temp` is the 'success' data and `temp.body` is a part of the json response. Then, the code stops at the second item of the list. Please help me with the data manipulation of recursive ajax. Thank you.

```
var idlist = ["10001","10002","10003"];
var index = 0;
function job(id) {
  $.get("https://cors-proxy.htmldriven.com/?url=http://www.olgame.tw/sds/robot_detail.php?id="+id, function( temp ) {
    $("body").append('<div id="myframe"></div>');
    $("#myframe").html(temp.body);  //This line causes problem. The entire code stops at here.
    $("div#myframe").remove();
    if (idlist[index+1] != undefined) {
      index++;
      job(idlist[index]);
    }  //index stops at '1'.
  });
}
job(idlist[index]);
```

The full code is [here](https://codepen.io/LL55/pen/ebypKv).

Comment: First, please reduce your code to the *absolute minimum* that is needed to reproduce your issue. Remove all the DOM manipulation and anything else that has nothing to do with the problem at hand. Second, please put all the remaining code into the question here, instead of linking to an external site. Questions here should be self-contained and not depend on external resources that might go away at any time.

Comment: Sorry for submitting the problem too quickly. I cleaned up the code so the problem is easy to understand now.

Comment: Are you sure that the `https://cors-proxy.htmldriven.com/` call is even successful? Your code only has a "success" callback, which means if the Ajax call returns an HTTP error, the callback function that does the recursive call will not be executed. Check the network tab in your browser's debugging tools to find out if the calls are successful. Add an "error" callback function to your code (you should generally do that for all Ajax calls. Letting errors go unhandled is not a good idea).

Comment: Also, you can't have more than one HTML element with the same ID. Your code would add `div#myframe` over and over again, that's not going to work very well. Use unique IDs, or don't use IDs at all. For what you do here, `$("<div>").html(temp.body).appendTo("body");` is completely sufficient.

Comment: @Tomalak, I finally figured it out. First, thank you for telling me to check the status of the response (it is indeed successful). Second, the repeated ID won't be a problem since it will be removed later. Lastly, the problem is that the javascript inside the response starts to execute once the response is put in the div. Therefore, my solution is to do a replace at the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Before the start of any 'data manipulation', any script within the response should be removed first to prevent possible ajax error.

```
var cont = temp.body.replace(/<script.*?<\/script>/g,'');
$("#myframe").html(cont);
```